# Why does dplyr fails to produce by line results?

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

both sum and + fail to give a result for each single line

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,1),x2=c(2,3),y1=c(NA,1),y2=c(NA,1))
df <- mutate(df, cost = prod(x1,x2,na.rm = T)+prod(y1,y2,na.rm = T),na.rm=T)
```

result:

```
  x1 x2 y1 y2 cost
1  1  2 NA NA    7
2  1  3  1  1    7
```

expected:

```
  x1 x2 y1 y2 cost
1  1  2 NA NA    3
2  1  3  1  1    4
```

Comment: `prod` is used when you want to multiply all the elements of a vector together. If you want multiplication element by element, just use the standard `*`. The only difference, AFAICT, is that you should replace `NA` values with `1` and then just define `cost = x1*x2+y1*y2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add `rowwise` otherwise `prod` does the multiplication on the whole column whereas we need the product of sum of each row

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(cost = prod(x1,x2,na.rm = TRUE) + prod(y1,y2,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#     x1    x2    y1    y2  cost
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2    NA    NA     3
#2     1     3     1     1     4
```